# AWS Amplify federated Okta authentication with hosted Cognito UI

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, aws-amplify, okta

I'm trying update an existing React Amplify app which authenticates using AWS Cognito user pools to also authenticate using Okta SSO integrated via SAML. Cognito was configured according to [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-okta-saml-identity-provider/) and I'm pretty sure everything is configured correctly, because when I use the "Launch Hosted UI" button from the Cognito console, I see the correct login dialog with both Okta and Cognito username/password panels and can authenticate using either.

I can't get the same panel to display when invoked using the `Authenticator` component in React though and I think it's because I don't have the `federated` parameter set correctly, but the only documentation I can find is for configuring with Google, Facebook, or Auth0, not Okta.

The error that I'm getting is:

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'oauthSignIn' of undefined`

and the code is set up as follows (but I've tried MANY permutations without luck):

```
const federatedInfo = {
    oauth_config: {
        domain: 'xxx.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
        clientID: 'zzz',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        audience: 'urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-yyy',
        responseType: 'token', //'token id_token', // for now we only support implicit grant flow
        scope: 'openid email',
        returnTo: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    }
};


   <Authenticator
        {...props}
        theme={AmplifyTheme}
        federated={federatedInfo}
        hideDefault={true}
        signUpConfig={authConfig.signUpConfig}
        onStateChange={(state, data) => {
            setAuthData({authState: state, user: data});
        }}
        children={[<Greetings/>, <SignIn federated={federatedInfo}/>, <ConfirmSignIn/>, <VerifyContact/>, <ForgotPassword/>, <RequireNewPassword/>]}
    />;
```

Any hints on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely follow you because I don't use Amplify, but worth checking whether you know you can use the authorize endpoint?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

i.e. you can create a static link with this format

https://[your cognito auth domain]/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=[your callback url]&response_type=token&client_id=[your client id]&identity_provider=[your identity provider]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's basically the URL that the "Launch Hosted UI" button, that I mentioned in my question, creates. That works fine, but because the app-based `Authenticator` component isn't configured correctly, it forces the user through a second non-federated authentication flow. I think I may have figured it out and will post an answer after some more testing.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up hacking around this by calling `Auth.federatedSignIn()` directly, conditionalized on presence of `oath.domain` in the Auth config, and only using the `Authenticator` component for local Cognito username/password login.

Not very elegant, but at least it's working. This whole area is woefully underdocumented by Amazon.

Comment: Could you expand on this? I'm in the same situation. How do you handle redirects?